# Pycord, can't import "commands" from discord.ext

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

I'm trying to add slash commands to my discord bot, but when I try to add `Option` with discord.app vs code says `Import "discord" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)`, and when I run it it says `ImportError: cannot import name 'commands' from 'discord.ext' (unknown location)` Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Option

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@bot.slash_command()
async def hello(ctx, user:Option(discord.Member, 'User to say hello to', required=True, default=None)):
    await ctx.send(f'Hello {user}!')
```

How can I fix this?

Edit: I fixed the vscode error by just doing `discord`, but I still haven't fixed the `ImportError`

Edit 2: I fixed the `ImportError` by using `pip install py-cord` instead of `pip install pycord`, but there's a new error: `line 3, in <module> from discord import Option ImportError: cannot import name 'Option' from 'discord'`

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: @Kalana `line 2, in <module> from discord.ext import commands
ImportError: cannot import name 'commands' from 'discord.ext' (unknown location)` I posted the full vscode error

Comment: What version of discord do you have installed?

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm using **Pycord** (although it should be quite similar since it's just a fork of discord.py) and pip tells me it's on 0.1.1

Comment: The latest tag on the pycord homepage is 1.7, so 0.1.1 seems horribly out of date.

Comment: @JohnGordon Weird, I tried to reinstall pycord and it said `Successfully installed pycord-0.1.1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to install the developer version of pycord (2.0.0) to get the `Options` property. you can install that with `pip install git+https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord`.

**You need git to do this.**

Comment: If this solves your problem, please mark it as the answer. It will help future readers who get the same problem as you.

Comment: @Kalana since its my answer i can only do it in 2 days. i suppose you could send the same and i could accept that one instantly.

Comment: Oh no, bro. I forgot that 2 days rule. You can Accept after that period. No rush

Answer (score -1):

The reason should be that you didn't install discord.py/pycord correctly.

You should try reinstalling the module.

For discord.py it's:

`pip install discord`

For pycord it's:

`pip install pycord`

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It should be `pip install py-cord`

Comment: Dude there are 3 ways to install pycord. `pip install pycord` and `pip install py-cord` or using the github link. I installed with github. By the way i solved it a long ago